# how can you make an array save as a new object each time a function is executed and not overwrite my old array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to make a simple register and log in system but I can only register 1 new username and password and the next time it is overwritten. I know the `[2]` after `objpeople` means it only writes on that line but what do put in to make it create a new object everytime?

```js
var objpeople = [
            {
                username: "adam",
                password: "coll",
                email: "neilcoll@mail.com"
            },
            {
                username: "jack",
                password: "mc",
                email: "jackmcgmail.com"
            }
        ];


    function register()
    {
        var Rusername = document.getElementById("Rname").value  
        var Rpassword = document.getElementById("Rpassword").value
        var Remail = document.getElementById("Remail").value
        var info = {};


        objpeople.push(info);
        objpeople[2].username=Rusername;
        objpeople[2].password=Rpassword;
        objpeople[2].email=Remail;


        let convobjpeople = JSON.stringify(objpeople)
        localStorage.people = convobjpeople

        document.getElementById("logbtn").innerHTML = "Cart";
        document.getElementById("logbtn").href="cart.html";
        localStorage.setItem('logged', 'true');
        return ;    
    }
```

edit: your code implementation

```
    var objpeople = [
            {
                username: "neil",
                password: "coll",
                email: "neilcoll@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                username: "jack",
                password: "mc",
                email: "jackmc@gmail.com"
            }
        ];



    function register()
    {
        let my_object =  {
                username: "",
                password: "",
                email: ""
            }
            var Rusername = document.getElementById("Rname").value  
            var Rpassword = document.getElementById("Rpassword").value
            var Remail = document.getElementById("Remail").value

            my_object.username=Rusername;
            my_object.password=Rpassword;
            my_object.email=Remail;

            objpeople.push(my_object)

            let convobjpeople = JSON.stringify(objpeople)
            localStorage.people = convobjpeople

            document.getElementById("logbtn").innerHTML = "Cart";
            document.getElementById("logbtn").href="cart.html";
            localStorage.setItem('logged', 'true');
            return ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to create objects and push them into an array?

Just initiate an object

```
let my_object =  {
                username: "",
                password: "",
                email: ""
            }
```

and when you want to assign values

```
var Rusername = document.getElementById("Rname").value  
var Rpassword = document.getElementById("Rpassword").value
var Remail = document.getElementById("Remail").value

 my_object.username=Rusername;
 my_object.password=Rpassword;
 my_object.email=Remail;
```

and finally

```
objpeople.push(my_object)
```

Edit: 
It shouldn't really be behaving like this but either ways you could just create a replica object that is not passed on to a server. So for example create a `objpeople2` and instead of `objpeople.push(my_object)` just do `objpeople2.push(my_object)` and then `objpeople = objpeople2` and finally

`let convobjpeople = JSON.stringify(objpeople)`. This way `objpeople2` is kept as it is.

Comment: that works but when I go to register again it overwrites the object in the array in localStorage, I want it to add a new object each time in the array not keep changing one

Comment: can you show me the code after you've incorporated my answer?